# Get back the id of each insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, output

Let's say we want to insert two users and I want to know the userId of each record I inserted.

Example:

Db:

```
User.lookup database with these columns:
UserId(PK, identity) | Username
```

Setup, insert two users:

```
declare @users table (uniqueId INT, name nvarchar(100));
insert into @users (0, 'TestUser')--Two users with the same name, they'll get a different userid in the db
insert into @users (1, 'TestUser')--Uniqueid is just an autonumber I use to tell the difference between them.
```

Insert statement:

```
insert into user.lookup (userName)
output inserted.userid
select name from @users;
```

This will return two usersIds, example 1 & 2. But how do I know which of the two users got which userId?

I can differentiate them in code with their 'uniqueid' I pass but I don't know how to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't correlate the inserted rows with the database-assigned IDs, at least not without inserting an alternate key as well.  INSERT ... OUTPUT will not let you output a row that wasn't actually inserted, so the column that correlates the un-keyed rows with the new key values has to be actually inserted.

So the options are:

1. To use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of `IDENTITY` and and either assign IDs to the table variable before insert, or assign IDs to the entities on the client, eg by calling [sp_sequence_get_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. Use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`. This is what Entity Framework Core does. See eg [The Case of Entity Framework Core’s Odd SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/case-entity-framework-cores-odd-sql/)

Comment: Thanks! Since we cannot change the sb structures, we have gone with the merge statement. That fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just `output` the id.  You can include other columns:

```
insert into user.lookup (userName)
    output inserted.*
    select name from @users;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebac0e3a8630f077f2fbeb2c1adb742b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon explained, one can output more than 1 column.

But just to put my 2 cents in, such insert doesn't really need an intermediate table variable.

> ```
> create table lookup (
>  lookupId int identity primary key, 
>  userName nvarchar(100),
>  createdOn datetime2 not null
>  default sysdatetime()
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into lookup (userName) values 
>  ('TestUser1')
> ,('TestUser2')
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into lookup (userName)
> output inserted.lookupId, inserted.userName
> values 
> ('Testuser3'),
> ('Testuser3')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> lookupId | userName 
> -------: | :--------
>        3 | Testuser3
>        4 | Testuser3
> ```

> ```
> select lookupId, userName
> --, convert(varchar,createdOn) as createdOn
> from lookup
> order by lookupId
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> lookupId | userName 
> -------: | :--------
>        1 | TestUser1
>        2 | TestUser2
>        3 | Testuser3
>        4 | Testuser3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9996370a610ecacd1b0cbd279937db0b)*